# In Z3Py, prove returns no counterexample

Tags: math, z3, smt, z3py, theorem

How can Z3 return a valid counterexample?
The following code

```
from z3 import *
set_param(proof=True)
x = Real('x')
f = ForAll(x, x * x > 0)
prove(f)
```

outputs `counterexample []`.

I don't have to use `prove`, but I want to find a valid counterexample to a formula like `f` in the example. How can I do it?

Comment: It seems it works as expected when I drop the `ForAll`. Could anybody explain why it works now, instead of just downvoting please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a model, you should really use `check`, and assert the negation of your formula in a solver context:

```
from z3 import *

s = Solver()
x = Real('x')
f = x * x > 0

# Add negation of our formula
# So, if it's not valid, we'll get a model
s.add(Not(f))

print s.check()
print s.model()
```

This produces:

```
sat
[x = 0]
```

Comment: Yes, I've looked into `prove` and that's what it does. Why is it necessary to drop the `ForAll`?

Comment: When models are constructed, Z3 only collects the variables at the top-level. With the quantifier `ForAll`, the variable becomes nested, and thus is ignored by Z3 when the model is built. You can see what z3py constructs by putting in different formulas and calling `print s.sexpr()` before you call `s.check()`.